# Modifying the polling rate of usb devices

Tags: usb-device, games

[This video](https://youtu.be/ahsO5bhBUtk?t=622) shows how increasing the polling rate decreases the average input lag for gaming controllers. Unfortunately, the software used to modify the polling rate is called [hidusbf](https://github.com/LordOfMice/hidusbf) and is only available for Windows. I found [gcadapter-oc-kmod](https://github.com/HannesMann/gcadapter-oc-kmod) which can be used to increase the polling rate of GameCube adapters on Linux, but I was wondering how I could modify the polling rate of any USB device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foremost, you need to find out what driver is your device using. For HID USB mice, keyboards and joysticks, the driver is `usbhid`. This driver has respective parameters `mousepoll`, `kbpoll` and `jspoll`. The value of these parameters is a number determining the polling period (T) in milliseconds, which is inversely proportional to the polling rate (f) and is rounded to a power of two. Thus, for polling rate of 250Hz set it to 4, for polling rate of 125Hz set it to 8, for polling rate of 1kHz set it to 1, and so on. If the parameter is set to 0 (default), the driver lets the HID device decide the optimal polling rate.

If you want to change this parameter on a running system, run the following commands (root access needed): `modprobe -r usbhid && modprobe usbhid mousepoll=1 kbpoll=2 jspoll=4`. The first part unloads `usbhid` driver, and the second part loads it with specified parameters (it's safe to omit the ones that you don't care about). Note that if the second command fails, you are likely to end up without functional input devices (the options to recover are reboot, access your system remotely or use PS/2 keyboard/mouse). If you want to make these changes persistent, add a line like `options usbhid mousepoll=1 kbpoll=2 jspoll=4` to `/etc/modprobe.d/usbhid.conf` or add parameters like `usbhid.mousepoll=1 usbhid.kbpoll=2 usbhid.jspoll=4` to your kernel command line.

However, if your device is not a HID device (like with the case of GameCube adapters), the driver might not have such parameter exposed to the user. In this case, you would need to modify this value in the source code of the driver and recompile it.